# how to parse XML which contains data in Norwegian language?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

how to parse XML which contains data in Norwegian language ?

Does i need any type of encoding with NSParser ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are worried about non-ASCII characters in the XML file.  Well you don't need to.  The first line of an XML file should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

where the encoding attribute tells you which character set was used to encode the characters in the file.  NSXMLParser will use that line to determine which character set it will use.  Once it gets to your methods, all the text will be in NSStrings which will be able to cope with your Norwegian characters automatically.

All you need to be concerned about is that the file really is encoded in the character set that the first line says it is.

Comment: Thanks for solving my doubt......    The problem is that it does not have <...  encoding="UTF-8"?> .

Answer (score 0):

The xml is the language which don't concern which kind of language you are using!! In xml there should be one start tag and it's end tag. Then you can parse using xml parsing.

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) is the tutorial to understand xml and 
[here](http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/) is the link to tutorial to parse the xml file.

may this will be help full to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, now my issue has been solved. The problem is that it does not have <...  encoding="UTF-8"?> .